# Java process is using so much of RAM

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse photon in my Ubuntu 18.04 with java 1.8, When i am opening the eclipse i had observed as java process is taking 750 MB to 1.2 GB of RAM as shown in the picture. This is making my system slow. Please help me and let us know how to solve this issue.

[image: System Monitor image]

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692206

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse is not a small application, it is packed with tons of features and capabilities that you may not be actively using.  Blaming Java is not accurate, as the JVM overhead is small in comparison to the rest of Eclipse.

In comparison, I have Visual Studio Code open with a medium sized project, and my usage is around 750MB for all of its processes (Not Java).  My PyCharm is at 830MB (also built on Java).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had recently switched from Windows to ubuntu and i had not got this issue previously when i am using windows for the same project.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is powerful ide and can use large amounts of memory. This mainly depend on how large are your project, and other case if you have **few opened projects**. Close unused projects, close unused perspectives and views. This is a basic to lower memory usage.
You can also configure eclipse.ini to use lower amount of memory and use garbage collection more often, but this can make ide not response very well, because of first statement in this answer, I mean large project.